# Rails <top (required)>: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nameerror, initialization, uninitialized-constant

I have a model called `class App::BaseModel` into a file called `base_model.rb`

Then I have a `message.rb` file which on the first line has the following:

`class App::Message < App::BaseModel`

When starting the server I get the error:

```
/path/to/app/message.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant App::BaseModel (NameError)
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Cheers

Comment: In which directory is the base_model.rb file located?

Comment: It's on `/path/to/app/app/models/my_app_name/`, the weird thing is that I was able to get this to work on a Mac but not on a Linux.

Answer (score 0):

for `base_model.rb` it should be => `class BaseModel WebActivity < ActiveRecord::Base`

and for `message.rb` it should be => `class Message < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a ActiveRecord made by hand, I'm not using the default Rails ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Rails have a naming convention, so if would like to put your model into App module (`App::BaseModel`), you should put the `base_model.rb` into app dir inside your models directory. Then Rails will load your file and class in it in a right way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have the files into `/path/to/app/app/models/my_app_name/`